# Twilio after-conference-end instructions are not executed properly

Tags: twilio, voice, twilio-twiml

I have a strange problem.

In my system 2 participants meet in conference.
First, `A`, calls and then is put to conference to wait while `B` is being dialed to join this conference. Then, after conference is ended by `A`, I want to execute some Twiml's to ask `B` few questions.

Below are my Twiml output to participants at last steps of the process:

For `A`:

```
<Response>
    <Gather numDigits="1">
         <Play>/somemusic.mp3</Play>
     </Gather>
</Response>
```

For `A`:

```
<Response>
  <Play>/THANK_YOU.mp3</Play><Redirect/>
</Response>
```

For `A`:

```
<Response>
    <Play>/PRE_FORWARD.mp3</Play>
    <Dial>
        <Conference waitUrl="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical" endConferenceOnExit="true">52d9771d4e1a41389983517</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

For `B`, after dialing him:

```
<Response>
    <Dial record="true"  action="http://XYZ/joinconference/name/52d9771d4e1a41389983517/conference_ended/1">
        <Conference waitUrl="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical" endConferenceOnExit="true">52d9771d4e1a41389983517</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

For `B`, after conference is ended:

```
<Response>
    <Gather numDigits="1">
        <Play>/QUESTION.mp3</Play>
        <Pause length="5"/>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Problem is : `B` does not hear `/QUESTION.mp3` completely. He hears only 1 second of this recording. After that call is hang. No `Gather` result submitted.

What could this be? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

First off, just check your call logs using the [Request Inspector](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-can-i-debug-my-application), as this can help with debugging your application.

I recreated what you are doing above and it worked perfectly. I believe the best option is to contact help@twilio.com with your Twilio Account SID, and the Twilio Support folk can dig into what is going wrong in your specific case.

Best of luck!